# Swagger UI is not loading in ADFS enabled system

Tags: jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui, adfs, pcf

Our application is deployed in Liberty PCF and it is ADFS configured. If we try to access the swagger UI, we are getting the error as **"Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings."**. and in network console showing,

**Status Code: 401 Unauthorized**

**{"error_description":"OpenID Connect client failed the request...","error":401}**

IF, we remove the ADFS configuration in this application then swagger ui is loading properly.

Here my questions are,
How to skip authorization for swagger UI? or
How to handle ADFS authentication for Swagger UI?

Your answer is more valuable. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like there's one blog post on this. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pratushb/2016/04/28/enable-swagger-to-authenticate-against-azure-ad/

Comment: https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/using-swagger-as-a-client-for-an-adfs-protected-api-49f9b4d773c